# how to create multiple bootstrap tooltips for dynamically generated elements

Tags: dynamic, multiple-instances, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have 2 selector and their own titles. My elements are generating dynamically by jquery.I wrote this code:

```
$("body").tooltip({
    selector: '.Edit',
    title: 'edit',
    placement: 'bottom'
});
$("body").tooltip({
    selector: '.Delete',
    title: 'delete',
    placement:'bottom'
});
```

Each of them works correctly alone,but it doesn't work together.
And I have to write title in js(not in data-original-title attribute in my HTML tag)

Comment: iirc the second tooltip will destroy the first tooltip invocation, thus, only ".Delete" is being triggered, right?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of invoking multiple tooltips, modify the placement variable to read it from the html element.

```
placement : $(this).data("placement") || 'top',
```